# How to update laravel project after changing javascript file and controller

Tags: javascript, php, apache, laravel

I added a .blade.php file and modified a controller and javascript file in my laravel project.
I'm unable to see the changed on the server(localhost).
Is there a command to update/refresh the project ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
php artisan view:clear
```

This will clear all compiled view files

Or other command that you can see by using:

```
php artisan list
```

Disable browser cache: [Disabling Chrome cache for website development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development)

Comment: I triedview:clear but it does't work, my javascript code is not working.But if I copy paste the code into console it works.

Comment: Are you getting old blade view or js or js which is in blade view?

Comment: The view is linked to js, the js code is responsible to addClass('active') to a component.But the code doesn't work.If i paste it in console it works.

Comment: What is your **doesn't work**? any error or work fine but running old code?

Comment: yes old code is running,the new js file is not loaded

Comment: OK, your problem maybe is that browser caching old script. Try to disable browser cache for debugging

Comment: Have you close all incognito windows and reopen?

Comment: yes, i have tried it.Somehow the old js file is loaded and not the new one

Comment: The problem was with the directory structure where the js file existed.

Answer (score 3):

On Chrome try to reload with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

This will not reload with cached files and updates will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
php artisan cache:clear

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel

To reflect your .js file changes :
You can clear the cache in history in the browser.

To reflect your php view file changes :
you can delete all autogenerated php files under views folder.
path to views folder : Storage -> Frameworks -> Views -> auto generated php files.

When added 'new file' is not detected, you can run 'php composer.phar update' (without quotes) command inside the project directory.